# Email signature for every email which is sent from salesforce case reply to gmail and mail came from gmail to case reply in salesforce

Tags: emailmessage

I have tried to get signature for each mail we are forwarding from case to outside to gmail and we are sending reply to case again from gmail to case email.Here when we send mail for the first time we can get signature for the email which we have send. when again we send no reply from case to gmail we are not getting signature which is already selected in default signature concept.How can we achieve to have email signature to be placed for every transaction of the mail.

Comment: Are you using a template? If so, do you have the field defined and populated for your default signature? Its not clear in your post, is the problem only with replies?

Comment: Yes we have created a HTML Template and we are using that template for sending mail.In HTML template we have used a field from user object to be inserted which consists signature of the user. Yes when a mail is forwarded first time we are getting signature but when we reply again we cant see signature again below the reply.

Comment: Is the signature appearing at the bottom of the reply email when it's forwarded as opposed to where the actual reply is being written, or not at all?

Comment: Yes the signature is being appeared at the bottom only . I mean the signature is not shown everytime reply is send only . The signature which is at the bottom is the signature which is shown when we forwarded the mail for the first time. But we require the signature to be shown for every reply at beneath the reply message .

Comment: I suspect that because it's shown the first time its forwarded at the very bottom, your template may think the requirement has been satisfied. You may need a different template to use for replies once an email has been forwarded.

Comment: If we change template for each time then we cnat get email history for that corresponding case . we require email history also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14648/discussion-between-salesforcesupport-and-crmprogdev).

Comment: sory I am not able to login into chat Would you please help me in the same window.

Comment: Sorry if we change different template for each transaction it is not correct procedure I think as we are increasing the reply mails according to that we have to change templates which is not a best way to achieve the task.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted a copy of your template someone might spot something about it that would be helpful to you.

Comment: {!User.RichText__c} this is syntax i have used to get data in richtext field. The same I have pasted in html template.Any message can be written in that HTML template. The value in Richtext area gets shown in the bottom of the html template.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your entire template code with all the fields shown, etc., minus any confidential identifying info by editing your original post?

Comment: I have used only one field which is used to display signature thats all.